# .Net Core Assembly issues

Tags: .net-core

I am converting an existing .Net framework 4.6.2 Project into a .Net core project. I have some of the DLLs in the .Net framework 4.6.2, while some DLLs are not supported in .Net core. Below is the list of those DLLs. Can any one give me the solution?

```
System.ComponentModel.Composition
System.Runtime.Remoting
system.serviceModel
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Take a quick look at this blog post by Jon Skeet on how to improve your questions: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: That being said, have you tried looking for the namespaces which you have listed on https://apisof.net/?

Comment: So? What is your question? .Net Core does not support the full .NET Framework. If you need the full framework, you will have to use it.

Comment: What's interesting about this, is that System.Web is supported by .NET Core version 2.0 (as per https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Web, which is a services provided by Microsoft so I'm inclined to believe it). OP, what have you tried and what are you actually trying to achieve? Also, have you looked into .NET Core's API surface at all?

Comment: `System.Web` and `System.ComponentModel.Composition` are both supported and provided for .NET Core version 2.0. But `System.Runtime.Remoting` and `System.ServiceModel` are not supported by .NET Core at this time. The short answer is just as @nvoigt says, if you need .NET Framework APIs, then use .NET Framework.

Comment: I added mainly articles, to make the sentences better readable, corrected singular/plural issues and tried to find the meaning of the whole paragraph - some DLLs (unified writing style) are not supported (or part of?) .Net-core. I'm not sure whether I met the intentions of the author, but hope so.

Comment: Thanks @JamieTaylor for your valuable answer

Comment: @karthikraja was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

The following is based on a comment I added to the question:

System.Web and System.ComponentModel.Composition are both supported and provided for .NET Core version 2.0, as can be seen [here](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Web#declarations) and [here](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.ComponentModel.Composition#declarations).

(as a side note: https://apisof.net/ is a wonderful resource, provided by Microsoft to aid in figuring out which APIs are available in the different .NET platforms).

But [System.Runtime.Remoting](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Runtime.Remoting#declarations) is not supported by .NET Core at this time.

The listing for [System.ServiceModel](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.ServiceModel#declarations) shows that it *is* supported in .NET Core, but only when Platform Extensions is included along side it.

If you need access to Windows or .NET Framework specific APIs, then it's recommended that you don't use .NET Core for the project or create a .NET Standard class library/project which includes the .NET Framework specific code and consume the outputs of that.

The following are some resources to help with .NET Core and .NET Framework API specific issues:

- https://apisof.net/
- [Immo Landwerth's videos on what .NET Standard is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YI4MurjfMn8&list=PLRAdsfhKI4OWx321A_pr-7HhRNk7wOLLY), and how it relates to the different .NET Platforms (he's the PM for .NET Standard)
- A blog post I wrote about [.NET Standard and how it fits into the .NET ecosystem](https://dotnetcore.gaprogman.com/2016/11/24/net-standard-what-it-is-and-how-it-applies-to-net-core/)
- A blog post from codeshare.co.uk describing the [key differences between .NET Framework and .NET Core](https://codeshare.co.uk/blog/what-is-net-core-7-things-you-should-know/)
- A blog post from [Stackify discussing the differences in .NET Framework and Core API space](https://stackify.com/net-core-vs-net-framework/)